# CSS Save image aspect ratio

Tags: css

I have some graphics of size in inches:

4.25 x 6.875
5.5 x 8.5
6 x 9
8.5 x 8.5
8.264 x 11.694

I want to do a reduced preview of that graphics (I'll iterate throught all size and I want to show each image in the same, only one DIV) but I want to save the aspect ratio. I'm wondering that would be the best size of that DIV to avoid deforming of each image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you set `max-width` and `max-height` on the image, but don't set `height` or `width`, then the image will be confined to the size you defined while keeping the aspect ratio.

Example:

```
<img src="big_image.png" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px;" />
```

If `big_image.png` were 4000 by 2000 pixels, it would be rendered as 100 by 50.

Answer (score 1):

My example controls the size of the images and div by css.
The div is set to auto, so it will adjust itself to the size of your images.
You can quickly control the size of the images in one go, instead of adjusting them one by one in the html code.

http://jsfiddle.net/KzXFm/

HTML

```
<div id='container'>
    <ul>
     <li>   
    <img src="http://static.dezeen.com/uploads/2009/01/2-port-house-antwerp-by-zaha-hadid-architects-sqwu-2port-house_antwerp_02.jpg">
        </li>
          <li>  
    <img src="http://static.dezeen.com/uploads/2009/01/2-port-house-antwerp-by-zaha-hadid-architects-sqwu-2port-house_antwerp_02.jpg">
        </li>
          <li>  
    <img src="http://static.dezeen.com/uploads/2009/01/2-port-house-antwerp-by-zaha-hadid-architects-sqwu-2port-house_antwerp_02.jpg">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    max-width:auto;
    max-height: auto;
    background: red;
}

img {
    max-width:20%;
    max-height: 20%;
}
```